# Style children with Styled Components in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

I have two separated components in different files (Container.tsx, Border.tsx) and I am rendering them like this:

```
<Border>
    <Container>{children}</Container>
</Border>
```

What I want is to give to the container a border using styles in the parent (Border.tsx), so it looks like this:

```
const Border = styled(View)<BorderProps>`
    child selector { border style } 
`
```

I want to do it this way to keep them as flexible as possible.
Is this viable?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to me, here it is worth setting border style and other options not in a separate component, but in the container itself, for example:

```js
const Container = styled.View`
flex: 1;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
`;
```

Comment: Well, I want to reuse Container without border and I don't want to pass it as a property to keep them flexible